# Typescript Does Not Seem To Have Javasvript Array.create(...) Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, nativescript, typescript2.0

I created a Vanilla Nativescript  Project and I could do the following:
`var arry = Array.create("byte",10);`

but in a similar TypeScript Project, the `Array.create(...)` function doesn't seem to be recognized.

I tried using the equivalent:

`var arry = new UintArray(10)`

but it appears the Android (Java) API function that requires a primitive byte is only accepting the array created using the Array.create(...) function.

How do I use `Array.create(...)` function in TypeScript?

Comment: How did you create your Nativescript TypeScript project?

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave this here (as a CW answer) so other JavaScript folks see it and know it's been covered, but it would appear that Nativescript has an [`Array.create`](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js#array-of-objects) method that's used to create Java arrays from JavaScript code. See [Artyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533541/157247) for a Nativescript answer to this question, which is probably more appropriate than this one.

---

There is no standard `Array.create` method in JavaScript. There's `[]`, `new Array`, `Array.of`, and `Array.from` along with various methods of existing arrays that create new ones (`map`, `filter`), but no `Array.create`.

```js
let a;

// `[]`:
a = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(a);

// `new Array`:
a = new Array("a", "b", "c"); // NOT RECOMMENDED
console.log(a);

// `Array.of`:
a = Array.of("a", "b", "c");
console.log(a);

// `Array.from`:
a = Array.from("abc");
console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

More in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: why is the second not recommended?

Comment: @Ifaruki - For a couple of reasons, but mostly because `new Array` has a footgun: `new Array("a")` creates an array with one entry, (`"a"`). `new Array(1, 2, 3)` creates an array with three entries (`1`, `2`, and `3`). But `new Array(3)` creates an **empty** array with `length` set to `3` (a sparse array). That's because if you give `new Array` just one argument, and that argument is a number, it's taken as a length for the new array; if you give it more than one argument, or an argument that isn't of type number, that/those argument(s) are used as values to populate the array with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NativeScript, you need to install typescript support using:

```sh
$ tns create my-app-name --template typescript  # Start a new project with typescript support
$ tns install typescript  # Add typescript support to an existing project
```

From https://nativescript.org/using-typescript-with-nativescript-when-developing-mobile-apps/

Comment: Do we know the OP didn't do that? They said they're trying to do this in a "TypeScript project" which suggests they have. Have you checked that `Array.create` type information is properly supplied by doing the above? It seems likely you're on the right track here though...